# Gitlab to Digital Ocean Auto Deploy

Tags: php, gitlab, autodeploy

Many of my projects are hosted at Digital ocean and i am using Gitlab. I have a way to deploy new releases to the servers. And i wanted to learn the appropriate/ best way to enable auto deploy from Gitlab to the server.